# How to reinstantiate OpenAI ChatCompletion object from string

Tags: python, openai-api

OpenAI python api call `client.chat.completions.create` now returns an object by default. How to reinstantiate that object after it was persisted to a database using `str(...)` method?

```
responseObj = client.chat.completions.create(...)

# returns ChatCompletion(id=...)
responseObjString = str(responseObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to reinstantiate OpenAI api object via `eval` you can encounter an error:

```
NameError: name 'ChatCompletion' is not defined
```

To fix it you have to import all OpenAI api classes that are present in a persisted string first. Sample code looks like. Add more imports if needed in your case.

```
from openai.types.chat import ChatCompletion
from openai.types.chat import ChatCompletionMessage
from openai.types import CompletionUsage
from openai.types.chat.chat_completion import Choice

...

responseObj = eval(responseObjString)
```

**Important notice.** This is not a production-ready nor production-safe code. Use it for the case you have persisted an object instead of JSON when migrating to a newer version of OpenAI api and would like to reinstantiate response from a persisted form.